# Perl: list the lines being run

Tags: perl, debugging

I am debugging big perl program. To minimize debugging I would like only to debug the lines actually run.

Is there a tool which I can run my program under, that will give me a program only containing the lines actually being used (e.g. by commenting out the rest)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Perl Debugger (http://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html).
Decent beginner's write up: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/05/perl-debugger/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want a coverage tool, like [Devel::Cover](http://search.cpan.org/~pjcj/Devel-Cover-1.17/lib/Devel/Cover.pm), which indicates the lines which are being executed during a run of the code.

For example, where you currently execute your code as

```
perl yourprog args
```

instead you run

```
perl −MDevel::Cover yourprog args
cover
```

This will generate an HTML report showing the code which is actually executed.

Comment: Does `cover` have a way of generating the code where all the lines with 0 are commented out?